# C++: Problems inheriting std::basic_streambuf

Tags: c++, tcp, stream, network-programming, iostream

I'd like to inherit `std::basic_streambuf` to implement a stream buffer based on a TCP connection. I don't understand exactly the role of the pointers `eback, gptr, egptr, pbase, pptr, epptr`. I was thinking of a stream buffer as an entity that simply lets u read characters from or write characters to a stream, and possibly to reposition the read/write pointers (not in my case). These pointers don't make sense for me, as I was thinking to implement a circular buffer for the input and output (so it's possible that, e.g., `gend < gbeg`). Do I really have to implement those pointers (`eback, gptr`, etc...), or I can just set them all to `nullptr` and everything will work fine? Or there is some function that would use them?

Comment: There is some code here that you can examine (or just use) [fdstream](http://www.josuttis.com/cppcode/fdstream.html). You can give the `fdstream`  a socket file descriptor. Alternatively `GCC` has `stdio_filebuf` as a library extension `#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>`. Again just pass it a socket file descriptor.

Answer (score 4):

(First off, it's great to see the decision to make a TCP streambuf rather than a TCP stream.)

Angelika Langer & Klaus Kleft have very good stuff on this, besides [the book](http://www.angelikalanger.com/iostreams.html), here is [a whole section of tutorials](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Topics.html#IOStreams).

However, streambufs often involve lots of boilerplate code, and, therefore, for an actual problem such as yours, I'd use [boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html), in particular [`source`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/source.html) (for a source tcp stream; obviously use `target` for the other way).

Note how this class has abstracted away the lower level ops you mentioned. You basically need to implement

```
std::streamsize read(char* s, std::streamsize n);
```

and it will take care of the rest for you (without much overhead).

As for your (reasonable sounding) idea to use a circular buffer, you might use [`boost::circular_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html). Alternatively, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023166/is-there-a-boostiostreams-bidirectional-device-for-a-blocking-boostasio-tc).

Comment: Thanx, @Ami. I'm not sure though I wanna use Boost as my program should be cross-platform (including Android), and it seems like Boost doesn't officially support Android.

Comment: Then I suggest Langer & Kleft, esp. [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/IOStreams/Excerpt/excerpt.htm) if you don't have the book.